# jQuery UI Map show street and city names

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-maps, kml, jquery-ui-map

In Google maps, just below the Map and Satellite view selectors, there is a tick box where you can turn labels on or off. Can this be done in code? This is my working code which is on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nbauers/2Dnwa/1/

Is it as simple as using "mapTypeId": google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID? I think I might have answered my own question.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>jQuery Google Maps KML Import</title>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../jq/jquery.ui.map.full.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test07.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>jQuery Google Maps KML Import</h1>
  <div style="margin:4px;" id="map_canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>

// ==== test07.js ====
$( document ).ready(function(){
    var $map_canvas = $( "#map_canvas" ),
        yourStartLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.6, 2.6);

    $map_canvas.css( "width", $( window ).width() - 24 );
    $map_canvas.css( "height", $( window ).height() / 2 );

    $map_canvas.gmap( {
      "center": yourStartLatLng,
      "mapTypeId": google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE });
    $map_canvas.gmap( "option", "zoom", 5 );    // Bigger zoom numbers zoom in.

    $map_canvas.gmap().bind( "init", function( ev, map ) {
        // ======================================================
        // ==== Import the KML
        // ======================================================
        var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: "http://nbest.co.uk/jsAQAsim/jsTests/test07f.kml",
            preserveViewport: true,
            suppressInfoWindows: false,
            map: map });
        // ======================================================
    });
});
```

Comment: I didn't see any tic box in google maps!

Comment: @Tilwin It shows up when you hover the mouse over the Satellite/Map selector.